# Android How find PID of GTALKService

Tags: android, google-talk

I'm working on an app to block GtalkService. I want just use iptables for this, but I cant find GtalkSerivce. I tried:

1. `ps` and `top` to list all processes but GtalkService wasn´t there
2. Install an app from Google Play and then use `logcat -v long *:V` to see the log, but I also nothing find there

I just wanted to find PID of the running GTalkService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTalkService is run in the process with the name `com.google.process.gapps`. You can check this if you install Google Apps on a emulator.

And I guess it will be difficult to kill it because the system restarts it. For instance, here the DDMS log. I've killed this process and the system has restarted it:

```
03-24 19:11:27.239: D/dalvikvm(167): Calling exit(1)
03-24 19:11:27.287: D/Zygote(33): Process 167 exited cleanly (1)
03-24 19:11:27.297: I/ActivityManager(61): Process com.google.process.gapps (pid 167) has died.
03-24 19:11:27.297: W/ActivityManager(61): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.gsf/.gtalkservice.service.GTalkService in 5000ms
03-24 19:11:32.047: D/dalvikvm(262): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1060K, 57% free 2816K/6535K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 89ms
03-24 19:11:32.327: I/ActivityManager(61): Start proc com.google.process.gapps for service com.google.android.gsf/.gtalkservice.service.GTalkService: pid=419 uid=10004 gids={3003, 1015, 2001, 1007}
03-24 19:11:32.637: I/ActivityThread(419): Pub com.google.settings: com.google.android.gsf.settings.GoogleSettingsProvider
03-24 19:11:32.647: I/ActivityThread(419): Pub com.google.android.gsf.gservices: com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider
03-24 19:11:32.657: I/GservicesProvider(419): Gservices pushing to system: true; secure: true
03-24 19:11:32.657: I/ActivityThread(419): Pub subscribedfeeds: com.google.android.gsf.subscribedfeeds.SubscribedFeedsProvider
03-24 19:11:32.756: I/ActivityThread(419): Pub com.google.android.providers.talk: com.google.android.gsf.talk.TalkProvider
03-24 19:11:33.027: D/GTalkService(419): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] ##### searchProvidersFromIntent
03-24 19:11:33.038: D/GTalkService(419): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] no intent receivers found
03-24 19:11:33.117: D/GTalkService(419): ##### Network broadcast (connected=true) type=mobile, state=CONNECTED
```

Comment: Thank You very much!!! I want to block it with iptables. It will be running but can not send anything to Google Server

Comment: I blocked port 5228 with iptables. This port is using from GtalkService to connect with Google Server. GTalk Monitor show status as off-line. And what I got? Android Market (Play Store) works!!!!! It must be something updated from Google now you can blocked GtalkSevice and used the Market and all other apps!!!! It seems that gtalk is not more the basis behind the c2dm push service!!!

Answer (score 1):

> Im working on an app to block GtalkService

That's a really, really bad idea.

gtalk is a fundamental system service and you will break many other applications on the device if you try and kill it. gtalk is the basis behind the c2dm push service, which many apps Google and otherwise depend on.

Comment: I know that there will be problems with Google calendar and GMail. What apps did you mean?

Comment: any app that uses c2dm. c2dm is THE push service for android. if you kill gtalk, you kill ALL apps that depend on push messages.

Comment: one more comment. I blocked port 5228 with iptables. This port is using from GtalkService to connect with Google Server. GTalk Monitor show status as off-line. And what I got? Android Market (Play Store) works!!!!! It must be something updated from Google now you can blocked GtalkSevice and used the Market and all other apps!!!! It seems that gtalk is not more the basis behind the c2dm push service!!!